# How to replay messages that have been processed through Azure Service Bus?

Tags: c#, azure, messaging

Given an enterprise systems architecture that relies on messaging capabilities of Azure Service Bus, in the event of corrupted system state, would it be possible to replay the commands to regenerate the system state?

Say there have been commands sent to the system, which are processed by the underlying microservices but due to a bug in a service, the resulting system state is not correct. We fixed the bug and deployed the new version of the service. Now we would like to clear the current state and recreate it by replaying the commands received by the system earlier.

As far as I understand, replaying messages is a concept being mentioned in event sourcing. When I search in the context of message brokers for enterprise system design such as Azure Service Bus, this capability does not seem to be common. Solace seem to support message replay according to [this article](https://solace.com/blog/products-tech/welcoming-replay). Though, we prefer to use Azure Service Bus (SaaS) rather than Solace (which would mean having to acquire IaaS resources) as the message broker.

The only solution I can think of is to implement a service as sort of an "event hub" which listens to all messages, serializes them, persists them. Then in the event of having to reprocess messages, it will deserialize messages (probably a selection of them) and send them back to Azure Service Bus following AMQP using a client library like [AMQP.Net lite](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite).

Are there any tools we can use instead of building such a service ourselves, which works together with Azure Service Bus?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at the [Azure Event Hubs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-hubs/) service, it should fit your needs pretty well.

**Update**

The purpose of using **Azure Event Hubs** in this scenario, is to store the messages that arrive through the **Service Bus** for possible later "replay" (or re-processing), not for replacing the **Service Bus**.
You can achieve this by using an **Azure Function** with:

- [Azure Service Bus Trigger binding for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger) to grab messages from a **Service Bus**

And then

- [Azure Event Hubs Output binding for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#output) to output a message to an **Event Hub**.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does azure event hubs integrate with azure service bus though? I tried to double check just now but I don't see that it is supported. Or did you mean to suggest that I use azure event hubs replacing azure service bus?

Comment: See update on azure functions triggers and binidings

Comment: I will make a poc to try the replay back from event hub into service bus. That's where my question lies. Getting messages to be stored in azure event hubs is fine. How will the messages be replayed into message bus, that's the part that I would like to get cleared. I guess since both the service bus and the event hubs use amqp for sending messages through, events deserialized by event hubs would be orchestrated correctly by the service bus? I will try if this works.

Comment: @Ssss I ended up writing my own service (called it EventPersister, an Azure Function) that stores every event into table store. Defined a common model for all events. This model contains "Id", "TopicName" and "Payload".  So any event incoming to the system must be in this form. Then EventPersister persists it in a single backed up table store and publishes the message according to the topic name and payload into Azure Service Bus. Not an ideal solution, given the fact that in case of EventPersister not being available, the rest of the system won't receive messages. So far this was acceptable..

Comment: Event Hubs is an awful suggestion for an event replay store - even on the premium tier it only supports 90 day retention.