# Replay Azure service bus messages

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, message-queue, azureservicebus

**Scenario**
A message arrives on a service bus queue which triggers an Azure function. The function inspects the message and forwards it onto one of two other queues. The message payload is between 3-15Kb and daily volume is expected to be around 40K messages.

**Problem**
Need to be able to replay old messages that the function has already processed. Can't go back to the publisher of the message.

I'm thinking of storing the messages in cosmosDB and having a http function that allows replay, it would read the messages from cosmos and push them back onto the input queue.

I can't help but think there's a better way of doing this with event hubs/event grid.
Any ideas welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Service Bus doesn't provide 'replay' ability, you need to use Event Hubs instead. See this answer that is similar, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53920295/14973743

Comment: The scenario you've described and the way you want to tackle it is 100% appropriate. Service Bus is not designed to store messages. That's where a DB comes in. And replaying messages requires some logic, which is a custom logic on demand. So HTTP trigger is a good option. In essence, you've answered your own question. Hence my comment rather than repeating what you've suggested in a form of an answer 

Comment: Thank you @SeanFeldman, I was hoping you'd join the thread:) I wanted to make sure I hadn't missed an obvious pattern that I should be using involving event hub/event grid to solve this. You're absolutely right in that my replay mechanism needs logic, such as only replay messages that the SB trigger function originally sent to queue "b". Many thanks.

Comment: @Klel7-4 as suggested by sean Feldman you have already provided your solution in question so post your answer here after building up your environment.